# Why Custom Java Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I understand we can to custom serialization by overriding readObject() and writeObject(). But what could be the need to do this ? Use cases ?

Also, Externalizable interface is also just a way to provide custom serialization or does it serve any other purpose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cases, out of the top of my head:

- restoring values of transient variables that are computed from other non-transient ones
- using a more compact, more efficient representation of the object for serialization than the default one
- maintain backward compatibility with previous versions of the class

the javadoc of Externalizable explains what it's used for.

Comment: Maintain backward compatibility by providing serialVersionUID in the code ? Am i right ?

Comment: Preserving the serialVersionUID value is indeed necessary, but not always sufficient. You have to read the object as it was before the changes, and populate the new fields of the class from the old serialized representation of the class. Same when serializing: you have to keep the same format as before, although the class isn't the same anymore.

Answer (score 3):

A familiar example from practice: `HashMap`. It has a lot of complex internal structure, yet has a fairly simple API, even including the customization parameters. If it used default serialization, it would have to serialize a fair amount of redundant information: empty buckets, empty parts of buckets, all the indices into the arrays, etc.

Instead, `HashMap` defines a simple and straightforward serialized form which transfers all, and no more than, the data needed to reconstruct it at the other end.

Comment: Great example. I had never read the read/writeObject() of HashMap before. It's even well documented as if it were an example demonstrating the usefulness of these methods. +1